# Usage of "let me know" in Letter writing

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

For my A1 exam, we have a letter writing part and there is a requirement that we should write a minimum of 30 words in the body of the letter. In some contexts, the usage of *please let me know* is useful [not only increases the word count, but also sounds polite ;-)]. For example consider this question and my answer.

> Q:
>   Sie waren im letzten Sommer in München in einem Deutschkurs. Ihr Lehrer war Herr 
>       Benradt, eine sehr sympathische Person. Schreiben Sie an Herrn Benradt.
>
> - Stellen Sie sich kurz vor.
> - Gibt es dieses Jahr wieder einen Kurs? Wann?
> - Sie möchten sich für den Kurs anmelden.
>
> A:
>   Bangalore, den 09.12.2012
>
> Lieber Herr Benradt,
>
> ich war im letzten Sommer in München. Ich war Student in Ihrem Deutschkurs. 
>       Ich habe Ihren Unterricht sehr gut gefunden. 
>       Bitte lassen Sie mich wissen, wenn Sie dieses Jahr wieder einen Kurs geben und wann beginnt der Kurs. 
>       Ich möchte mich für den Kurs anmelden.
>
> Mit Freundlichen Grüßen,
>       ABC XYZ

Is the above usage of "Bitte lassen Sie mich wissen" correct?

As always, I am open to learn better word usage and sentence constructions. Please give your suggestions.

Comment: I corrected some minor mistakes. However, I'd say "Bitte lassen sie mich wissen, **ob** sie dieses Jahr wieder einen Kurs geben und wann dieser beginnt." Regarding the second sentence, I'm not sure if you wanted to write "Ich habe Ihr Unterrichten sehr gut empfunden" where "Unterrichten" is the action. That's possible but it's more commmon to say it as it stands now.

Comment: Thanks you for the edits. Can you please tell me what is empfunden? I learned *gefunden* as partizip II for *finden*.

Comment: "Empfunden" is the past participle of "empfinden". And since you asked for other ways of saying it, you can also say "Bitte geben Sie mir Bescheid..." (written) or "Bitte sagen Sie mir Bescheid..." (spoken) for "Please let me know..." or "Please inform me..."

Comment: Oh, sorry. I actually was about writing "gefunden" as you did. That's absolutely fine. It's even better as "empfunden". Don't know why I wrote that. It would be OK though in the way of saying "Ich habe ihre Art zu unterrichten als sehr angenehm empfunden." in the meaning of it's a way of "productive teaching". However, it wasn't what I intended to write.

Comment: @Em1 Thank you for all the tips and suggestions.. I got 87 in my A1 exam :-).. A2 begins on Jan 5th.. I will come up with some more doubts then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Bitte lassen Sie mich wissen* is correct (pretty easy); the tough part is writing the subordinate clause after it.

> A:
>
> Bangalore, den 09.12.2012
>
> Lieber Herr Benradt,
> ich war im letzten Sommer in München und habe an Ihrem Deutschkurs teilgenommen.

*Student* is someone who goes to the university; *Schüler* is someone who goes to school. Both terms are rarely used for *Erwachsenenkurse*. *Teilnehmer* is probably the best term.
Regarding the content... do you count this as a *Vorstellung*? A stranger writing to you "Hello, last summer I was in in your town!"

> Ich fand Ihren Unterricht sehr gut.

simply better style.

> Bitte lassen Sie mich wissen, wenn Sie dieses Jahr wieder einen Kurs anbieten und wann der Kurs beginnt.

I would suggest *anbieten*; while *geben* is correct, it simply sounds *holprig*. More importantly you have to **reverse the structure of the subordinate clause**!

> Ich möchte mich für den Kurs anmelden.

I find it logically a bit weird to register for a course of which the person doesn't even know if and when it's happening; but whatever. You can increase the word-count here again.

> Falls ja, würde ich mich gerne für den Kurs anmelden.

But you could also make it very different:

> Ich fand Ihren Unterricht sehr gut und würde gerne wieder an einem Kurs von Ihnen teilnehmen. Bitte lassen Sie mich wissen, ob Sie dieses Jahr wieder einen Kurs anbieten und wann der Kurs beginnt. Falls ein Kurs schon geplant ist, wie könnte ich mich für diesen Kurs anmelden?

Comment: There's another thing: I believe there are two different 'let me know': a) *"Bitte lassen Sie mich wissen, ob …"*  versus b) *"Bitte lassen Sie **es** mich wissen, wenn/falls X zutrifft."* The second one with the additional 'es' applies when a conditional clause is used: 'Let me know / notify me  should X be the case.'